# android how to get all video uploads by another user using youtube data api v2?

Tags: android, youtube-api

I have been trying to get all the videos upload by particular user. I tried this url
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc but only getting first page video list.

There are around 250 videos uploaded by this user but i m getting only few. On website we get more videos by loading "load more" button but with api i dont know know how to get it.

Can anybody help me for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to also send [max-results](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#max-resultssp) and [start-index](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#max-resultssp) to gdata api for querying next 25(max 50) results because by default gdata  api return only fist 25 results

For example to get next 25 results :

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads?v=2&alt=json&max-results=25&start-index=10

Comment: Thanks my problem solved but can you clarify one thing that if we change jsonc to json in url it gives different result.

Comment: @Hitendra : you can see more information about jsonc here https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc